# WooCommerce add to cart validation: prevent add to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a probleme with woocommerce that im trying to fix for few days.

I am creating a website for a guy and he wanted me to add a custom input on the product page, I couldn't do it myself so I used a freelancer online for it.

On the product page I have an add-to-cart button, quantity input and date input.

The "date input" is the freelancer did.

The thing is that when the $_REQUEST['thedate'] is empty the custom error popup but the product still added to the cart.

the code:(functions.php)

```php
function add_the_date_validation() { 
  if ( empty( $_REQUEST['thedate'] )) {
    wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter a date.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'add_the_date_validation', 10, 5 );
```

the view:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a75P6.png

- How can i prevent the product to add itslef to the cart?

other codes the freelancer did:

```php
function save_add_the_date_field( $cart_item_key, $product_id = null, $quantity= null, $variation_id= null, $variation= null ) {
  if( isset( $_REQUEST['thedate'] ) ) {
    WC()->session->set( $cart_item_key.'_the_date', $_REQUEST['thedate'] );
  }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'save_add_the_date_field', 1, 5 );

function render_meta_on_checkout_order_review_item( $quantity = null, $cart_item = null, $cart_item_key = null ) {
  if( $cart_item_key && WC()->session->__isset( $cart_item_key.'_the_date' ) ) {
    echo $quantity. '<dl class="">
                      <dt class="">Date: </dt>
                      <dd class=""><p>'. WC()->session->get( $cart_item_key.'_the_date') .'</p></dd>
                    </dl>';
  }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'render_meta_on_checkout_order_review_item', 1, 3 );

function the_date_order_meta_handler( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
  if( WC()->session->__isset( $cart_item_key.'_the_date' ) ) {
    wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, "the_date", WC()->session->get( $cart_item_key.'_the_date') );
  }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'the_date_order_meta_handler', 1, 3 );

function the_date_force_individual_cart_items($cart_item_data, $product_id) {
  $unique_cart_item_key = md5( microtime().rand() );
  $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = $unique_cart_item_key;

  return $cart_item_data;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data','the_date_force_individual_cart_items', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would have said that you should use [Product Add-Ons](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/product-add-ons/) but it doesn't seem to have a date picker. Anyway, I would try modifying your validation function as follows:

```
function add_the_date_validation( $passed ) { 
if ( empty( $_REQUEST['thedate'] )) {
    wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter a date.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    $passed = false;
}
return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'add_the_date_validation', 10, 5 );
```

Instead of returning `TRUE` you want to return the current status of the `$passed` variable. I can't promise that will work, because I am not going to set up the rest of the code required to test it, but this is similar to what I have done many times.

On another note, unless you mean to apply this validation to every product in your store, you need to limit this function with some additional conditional logic.

Comment: Should be `add_filter` not `add_action`

Comment: For me this throws an validation error as it should, but still adds the item to cart as it shouldn't

Comment: @Sisalik are you using the cart block?

Comment: @helgatheviking Apparently my troublemaker was in the hook `add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'action_add_to_cart', 10, 5);`. Function `woocommerce_add_to_cart` needs to validate the date, too.

Comment: @Sisalik I'm not certain that's right. You shouldn't even be getting to the `woocommerce_add_to_cart` hook if validation fails as that hook is nested inside the `WC_Cart->add_to_cart()` method. Unless you have a custom add to cart handler that is not checking validation first? You might want to spin up your own question with the necessary details.

Comment: @helgatheviking You're right,that is not the problem. Still my validation throws errors, but the item is added to the cart. Don't get it, if it has something to do with the processing order of functions. What should be the correct order?

Comment: The answer below sorted this out :)

Comment: Sorry, which answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55304564/383847 ? So higher priority? That's weird to me as all the callbacks attached to `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` should run (unless one callback is explicitly passing `TRUE` after you've set it to `FALSE`

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue and after much trial and error the fix was to adjust the $priority parameter (10 is default) in :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'add_the_date_validation', 10, 5 );
```

As per usual, I tried everything else first...changed this to 15 and bingo..!  I guess it was running ahead of code ranked lower priority, which then let items into cart.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Allow only pre-defined quantity from specific per category in the cart
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'allowed_quantity_per_category_in_the_cart', 10, 2 );
function allowed_quantity_per_category_in_the_cart( $passed, $product_id) {

  $running_qty = 0;
  $restricted_product_cats = $restricted_product_cat_slugs = array();

    //Specify the category/categories by category slug and the quantity limit
    $restricted_product_cats[] = array('cat_slug'=> 'skip-bins', 'max_num_products' => 1); // change here
    //$restricted_product_cats[] = array('cat_slug'=> 'caliper-paint-kit', 'max_num_products' => 4); //change here
    foreach($restricted_product_cats as $restricted_prod_cat) $restricted_product_cat_slugs[]= $restricted_prod_cat['cat_slug'];

    // Getting the current product category slugs in an array
    $product_cats_object = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
    foreach($product_cats_object as $obj_prod_cat) $current_product_cats[]=$obj_prod_cat->slug;

    // Iterating through each cart item
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key=>$cart_item ){


        // Check if restricted category/categories found
      if( array_intersect($restricted_product_cat_slugs, $current_product_cats) ) {

        foreach($restricted_product_cats as $restricted_product_cat){
          if( in_array($restricted_product_cat['cat_slug'], $current_product_cats) && has_term( $current_product_cats, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] )) {

                    // count(selected category) quantity
            $running_qty += (int) $cart_item['quantity'];

                    // Check if More than allowed products in the cart
            if( $running_qty >= $restricted_product_cat['max_num_products'] ) {

                        //limit to maximum allowed
                        //WC()->cart->set_quantity( $cart_item_key, $restricted_product_cat['max_num_products'] ); // Change quantity

                        // Get the category information
              $catinfo = get_term_by('slug', $restricted_product_cat['cat_slug'], 'product_cat');

              wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'Maximum of  %s '.($restricted_product_cat['max_num_products']>1?'skip bin ('.$catinfo->name.') are':'skip bin').' allowed in the cart. Please remove the existing Skip Bin from the cart to add the new Skip Bin',  $restricted_product_cat['max_num_products'] ), 'error' );
                         ///WC()->cart->empty_cart();
                        $passed = false; // don't add the new product to the cart
                        // We stop the loop
                        break;
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
              return $passed;
}
```

Answer (score -13):

Yes, sorry i'am new in this forum.
However i have found a solution, i have edit directly **class-wc-cart.php** at line 900, and i have copy the function before the if:

```
if($passed!=false)
{
    do_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data );
}
```

Now for me it works, i know that isn't the most correct solution but for the moment it works, i have only **to be careful** when i will **update woocommerce**

Comment: This is not an answer to the question

Comment: Very bad solution to be posted here, no one should try this. Never edit 3rd party plugin or WP core code! Use hooks!