# javascript woocommerce form validation on add to cart buton before adding to cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom page that displays a product with variations, a custom field and add to cart button.
I need to trigger some validation in javascript when the add to cart button is clicked, but if the form doesn't validate, then add to cart can't be performed.

I'd like to know if it's possible to achieve.

First I tried to do as explained here :
[WooCommerce add to cart validation: prevent add to cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736863/woocommerce-add-to-cart-validation-prevent-add-to-cart/56341537#56341537)

It's working great and I'd like to be able to use this code but for me it can't be because :
- I'm using a custom page and not the usual woocommerce product page
- This means that after validation, I'm redirected to the standard woocommerce page which is blank

That's why I really need to use Javascript to perform this: 
- javascript or jquery function triggered on the add to cart click
- then the function checks it everything is ok
- if yes, then product can be added to cart
- if no, an alert is displayed and the user remains on the same page, nothing added to cart.

I tried to be as clear as possible. 
Hoping I can get some help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just use that code then after validation re-direct the user using the link http://yourdomain.com/?add-to-cart=25     where 25 is the product id. If using variations it would be the variation id.

Comment: You said 'use that code' but i can't see any code from you... And after validation i need to redirect to a specific page, not the add-to-cart page.

Comment: So what I meant by use the code is use the code in the link you posted.  So do you still want the item to get added to cart or not?  And after validation you can redirect using javascript with window.location.replace("http://www.example.com");

Comment: So you can validate initially with js. if its good redirect using the add to cart link, if its not then redirect to the page you want to redirect to.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way:

```
function so_validate_add_cart_item( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = '', $variations= '' ) {
<script>
  jQuery(function($){
       jQuery(document).on('click', '.single_add_to_cart_button', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // your validation here
       });  
    });
</script>
}
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'so_validate_add_cart_item', 10, 5 );
```

Comment: No, it's not working. Actually it does nothing... and leads me to a blank page. Anyone else ? I'm sure it can be possible...